# Why/how are the banking systems that robust?

Tags: fault-tolerance

I'm a developer, so I understand (a bit) how computers work, and how softwares work and fail.

In all softwares I've dealt with (as a developer or as a user), I've always seen small or huge bugs:

- Even in systems well designed/implemented you encounter design/implementation bugs.
- Even sites/softwares exceptionally well developed (high-skilled engineers and/or high-budget projects) are subject to problems (StackOverflow is down from time to time, a big Web company database may fail with a few seconds/minutes data loss despite a good mirroring technology, a virus may corrupt files at an e-commerce or social site, etc.).
- Even in the *medical industry*, we see from time to time bugs or other important problems leading to a serious outage.
- Even [embedded systems in space rockets may have bugs leading to the destruction of the rocket](http://sunnyday.mit.edu/accidents/Ariane5accidentreport.html).

However, with banking systems, this seems to never occur:

- I've never heard about data loss with credit card transactions.
- I've never heard about an ATM failing to provide a customer with cash because the back-end is down (the ATM may be broken, but it's always because of a fault on the ATM side).
- I've never heard about an online bank account failing to report the exact list of operations (the Web site may be down, but the data is always accurate at the end).
- I've never heard about a virus corrupting banking information resulting in an actual data loss.
- And even when I think about the *old days*, when my parents used to receive paper versions of their bank reports, in the 80s (and I assume the same was true in the 70s), *there was no error at all*.

**How could the banking system be the only one perfectly error-proof, since the early ages of computer science, while all other systems fail from time to time?**
This is even more surprising when you consider the amount of interoperability you need accros all banks and countries! And this works fine since 10s years.

Comment: http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-38741339

Comment: You never heard of bugs in banking systems does not mean there is none. The one I cited above is a famous one. I also heard and personally encountered banking system bugs that did not make headline news.

Comment: @scaaahu, yep, of course. But as a daily user of the banking system, I never heard about bugs in it. I also know a lot of other users... However, with *all* other systems, I've seen minor to major bugs. As well as my family and friends do.

Comment: @scaaahu: the link you posted seems to be about hacking a _client_ machine (ATM), not the back-end.

Comment: ATMs are connected to the backend. I don't know the details of the robbery. I heard the thieves stole codes from London branch. If you are interested, you can dig out the story.

Comment: I think it's partly confirmation bias: you only interact with the banking system only a few times a week with single action, whereas with SO or webshops you have a extended multi-action interactions with it.

Comment: I'm sure this is not a bias: my family, my friends, and I never had any data loss at the back-end of a banking system. I "interact" with the banking system many times a day: wire transfert, credit cards, checks. I do financial operations. As well as billions of people, every day. Not a penny is never lost, despite the amount of transactions, the many different systems interoperating together, and the complexity of the business rules. And this has been for 10s years.